# Click button to continue with next method

Tags: c#

When I click a button, I want to run multiple methods one after another. I want a click button allow the next method in the queue to execute.

A message box does exactly what I want but I hate message boxes.

This is what I'm trying to implement:

```
private void teststart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    step1();
    //Wait for button to be clicked
    step2();
    //wait for button to be clicked
    step3();
    //wait for button to be clicked

}

private void continuebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //button to be clicked
}
```

Comment: btw. I don't think multi-threading is a good choice in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my particular solution, I started with the solution I posted above. After more google, I found the easy way was to

```
do
{Application.Doevents()}
while (step == false)
```

the only bug i found in this is that i had to click the button twice, so i disabled the button, which i wanted to do anyway, then renabled it later. I've read this is bad coding, but I have yet to find an easier way to accomplish this goal.

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain a static variable (i.e. step count) and each time the correct button is pressed, increase the step count.

```
static int _step = 0;

private void teststart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if(_step > 0)
    {
      // already started
      return;
    }
    step1(); 
    _step++;

} 

private void continuebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if(_step == 0) 
    {  
        // start button must be pushed first
        return;
    }

    if(_step == 1)
    {
      step2(); 
      _step++;
    }
    else
    {
      step3(); .
      _step = 0;  // start over
    } 
}
```

Comment: Same idea, but with code, making your method better. Though it's lacking a 'multiple click guard', but then again the form blocks while continuebutton is getting processed.

Comment: Making this field static seems like a bad idea to me. Static and mutable is rarely a good combination.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - probably a class var would work, but I don't have enough of the code to determine that.  Good point though.

Comment: I'd change the `if`'s into a `switch`.

Comment: I feel stupid, I was way over complicating this. Your suggestion is perfect. Thank you very much Chris. I have now set all my individual tests to different "step" values with my continue button reverting the program back to default settings when completed. I then set my start test buttons to different step values and I let the continue button handle the flow control.

Answer (score 1):

make a queue and delegate for your step function it will more practice. I have done a sample that enqueue delegate (step return string) when you click on button it dequeue the queue that contains all your steps:

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public  delegate string mystep ();
        public Queue<mystep> queuestep;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            queuestep = new Queue<mystep>();
            queuestep.Enqueue(step1);
            queuestep.Enqueue(step2);
            queuestep.Enqueue(step3);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (queuestep.Count >0)
            {
           mystep currentstep =  queuestep.Dequeue();
           textBox1.Text =currentstep();
           }
        }

        private string step1()
        {
            return "step1";
        }
        private string step2()
        {
            return "step2";
        }
        private string step3()
        {
            return "step3";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1: This is definitely the way to go. Other answers are ugly hacks.

Comment: Although in your case `mystep` is really a `Func<string>`

Comment: howerver if function have different pattern you have to define only as many delegate

Answer (score 0):

This isn't particularly C#, but here's a method that can do what you want.

Keep a class variable, like `Step` or anything of type integer.
Inside the `continuebutton_click`-Method, check if `Step % 2 == 0`, and if so, trigger the next method in line (using a switch/case or something) and increment Step by one.
Once the method is done, increment the Step count once more.

That way, you get the desired behaviour without using a message box.

Answer (score 0):

its fugly but works, thanks for the advice. The code does exactly what i want. I am sure there is a more elegant way of pulling this off but as stated i am still a noob and this works.

```
        step++;
        if (step == 502 || step == 392 || step == 305 || step == 14 || step == 313 ||          step == 324 || step == 332 || step == 344 || step == 357 || step == 363 || step == 373 || step == 384 || step == 122 || step == 408 || step == 222)
        {defaults();}

        if (step == 300)
        {firstlo();}

        if (step == 1 || step == 301)
        {firstlo1();}

        if (step == 2 || step == 302)
        {firstlo2();}

        if (step == 3 || step == 303)
        {firstlo3();}

        if (step == 4)
        {loinband();}

        if (step == 5 || step == 311)
        {loinband1();}

        if (step == 6)
        { secondlo();}

        if (step == 7 || step == 321)
        { secondlo1(); }

        if (step == 8 || step == 322)
        { secondlo2(); }

        if (step == 9)
        {currents();}

        if (step == 10)
        {outputpower();}

        if (step == 11 || step == 341)
        { outputpower1(); }

        if (step == 12 || step == 342)
        { outputpower2(); }

        if (step == 215)
        {satatt();}

        /*if (step == 351)
        { satatt1(); }*/

        if (step == 351 || step == 101 || step == 216)
        { satatt2(); }

        if (step == 352 || step == 102 || step == 217)
        { satatt3(); }

        if (step == 353 || step == 103 || step == 218)
        { satatt4(); }

        if (step == 354 || step == 104 || step == 219)
        { satatt5(); }

        if (step == 355 || step == 105 || step == 220)
        { satatt6(); }

        if (step == 106 || step == 211)
        { lineargain(); }

        if (step == 361 || step == 107 || step == 212)
        { lineargain1(); }

        if (step == 108 || step == 213)
        { compression(); }

        if (step == 109 || step == 371 || step == 214)
        { compression1(); }

        if (step == 110 || step == 208)
        { outputinband(); }

        if (step == 111 || step == 381 || step == 209)
        { outputinband1(); }

        if (step == 112 || step == 382 || step == 210)
        { outputinband2(); }

        if (step == 113 || step == 207)
        { ifrl(); }

        if (step == 114)
        { twotone(); }

        if (step == 115 || step == 401 || step == 201)
        { twotone1(); }

        if (step == 116 || step == 402 || step == 202)
        { twotone2(); }

        if (step == 117 || step == 403 || step == 203)
        { twotone3(); }

        if (step == 118 || step == 404 || step == 204)
        { twotone4(); }

        if (step == 119 || step == 405 || step == 205)
        { twotone5(); }

        if (step == 120 || step == 406 || step == 206)
        { twotone6(); }

        if (step == 304 || step == 13 || step == 501 || step == 312 || step == 323 || step == 331 || step == 343 || step == 356 || step == 362 || step == 372 || step == 383 || step == 391 || step == 121 || step == 407 || step == 221)
        {
            cont.Hide();
            instructions.Text = "Test Complete\n\n\nPress continue to return program to start condition\nor close program.";</code>
```